# How to detect when another app uses audio output?

Tags: android, audio, broadcastreceiver, audio-streaming

I am working on a radio application and I am facing a problem that is: while my application is running and using audio output, if another application used the audio output, the sound then overlaps. I need to turn off my application's media player once the audio output is used by another application. How to detect when the audio output is used by another application?

Comment: look into[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener.html](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener.html)

Comment: see http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html